# UISwitch is not updating because reloaddata

Tags: ios, objective-c

I usually like to solve problems on my own, but I am having an issue. Right now I have trying to replicate the default IOS clock app where they have a tableviewcell with uiswitches.
Right now I have a `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL alarmOn;` to track the switches, I am unsure how to track when I have multiple switches I know I have to use an array or an `NSNumber` but I am quite unsure. The problem right now is when I create a clock it displays on the cell and I toggle the switch on. Then if I want to edit the time on the clock, i click inside the cell and go back to the tableviewcontroller the `UISwitch` is turned back off. I know the problem is viewillload when I `reload` the data again but I don't know the way around this. I have to `reload` the data because when I edit the time within the clock, I want to update the tableview to display the correct time.

Right now

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Create a switch button on each cell
    UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    //[switchView setOn:NO animated:YES];
    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [switchView setOnTintColor:COLOR_RGB(0, 174, 239, 1.0)];
    self.alarmOn = (switchView.on) ? YES : NO;

    cell.accessoryView = switchView;

    return cell;
}
```

**UpdateSwitch**

```
 - (void)updateSwitch:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *switcher = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if (switcher.on)
    {
        [switcher setOn: YES animated:YES];
        self.alarmOn = YES;
        NSLog(@"ON");
    }
    else
    {
        [switcher setOn: NO animated: YES];
        self.alarmOn = NO;
        NSLog(@"OFF");
    }

}
```

**ViewWillLoad**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the switch values in a `NSMutableDictionar` keyed by `indexPath` and restore them later. As follows:

Use this category for finding the parentTableViewCell for the UISwitch:

```
@implementation UIView (ParentTableViewCell category)

- (UITableViewCell *)parentTableViewCell
{
    // iterate up the view hierarchy to find the table cell containing this view
    UIView *aView = self.superview;
    while(aView != nil) {
        if([aView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            return (UITableViewCell *)aView;
        }
        aView = aView.superview;
    }
    return nil; // this view is not within a tableView cell
}

@end
```

And then:

```
- (void)viewWillLoad:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillLoad:animated];

    self.switchValues = [MSMutableDictionary new];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Create a switch button on each cell
    UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] init];

    // Get previous switchValue. Will be NO if no previous value
    BOOL switchValue = [self.switchValues[indexPath] boolValue];
    [switchView setOn:switchValue animated:YES];

    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [switchView setOnTintColor:COLOR_RGB(0, 174, 239, 1.0)];
    self.alarmOn = (switchView.on) ? YES : NO;

    cell.accessoryView = switchView;

    return cell;
}

- (void)updateSwitch:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *switcher = (UISwitch *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [switcher parentTableViewCell];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // Store the value as an NSNumber keyed by indexPath
    self.switchValues[indexPath] = @( switcher.on );

    if (switcher.on)
    {
        [switcher setOn: YES animated:YES];
        self.alarmOn = YES;
        NSLog(@"ON");
    }
    else
    {
        [switcher setOn: NO animated: YES];
        self.alarmOn = NO;
        NSLog(@"OFF");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out right now. Do I make a new file for the UIView?

Comment: It's not needed to make new file for the `UIView` category, but it's recommended if you plan to use this convenience method from additional files in your code.